# Angular form control is invalid in component init

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to made a form to change password for my website. But whenever I am submitting the form it is showing invalid. Even every control is set required for validators. But it is submitting null data! Don't know if there is any problem in formcontrols. I can't find any issues here. Here I am adding my codes:

HTML:

```
<form [formGroup]="changePasswordForm" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
        <div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutGap="1rem">
          <div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutGap="1%">
            <mat-label>Present Password</mat-label>
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
              <input
                [type]="presentPasswordVisibility ? 'text' : 'password'"
                formControlName="presentPassword"
                matInput
                pattern="^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z\d]{8,16}$"
                placeholder="Type present password here"
                required
              />
              <mat-icon
                (click)="presentPasswordVisibility = !presentPasswordVisibility"
                class="cursor-pointer"
                matSuffix
              >
                {{
                  presentPasswordVisibility ? "visibility" : "visibility_off"
                }}
              </mat-icon>
              <mat-error *ngIf="hasError('presentPassword', 'required')"
                >Password is required
              </mat-error>
              <mat-error *ngIf="hasError('presentPassword', 'pattern')"
                >Password must be between 8-16 characters and at least one
                letter and one number
              </mat-error>
            </mat-form-field>
          </div>

          <div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutGap="1%">
            <mat-label>New Password</mat-label>
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
              <input
                [type]="newPasswordVisibility ? 'text' : 'password'"
                formControlName="newPassword"
                matInput
                pattern="^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z\d]{8,16}$"
                placeholder="Type new present password here"
                required
              />
              <mat-icon
                (click)="newPasswordVisibility = !newPasswordVisibility"
                class="cursor-pointer"
                matSuffix
              >
                {{ newPasswordVisibility ? "visibility" : "visibility_off" }}
              </mat-icon>
              <mat-error *ngIf="hasError('newPassword', 'required')"
                >Password is required
              </mat-error>
              <mat-error *ngIf="hasError('newPassword', 'pattern')"
                >Password must be between 8-16 characters and at least one
                letter and one number
              </mat-error>
            </mat-form-field>
          </div>

          <div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutGap="1%">
            <mat-label>Confirm New Password</mat-label>
            <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
              <input
                [type]="confirmNewPasswordVisibility ? 'text' : 'password'"
                formControlName="confirmNewPassword"
                matInput
                placeholder="Type present password here"
                required
              />
              <mat-icon
                (click)="
                  confirmNewPasswordVisibility = !confirmNewPasswordVisibility
                "
                class="cursor-pointer"
                matSuffix
              >
                {{
                  confirmNewPasswordVisibility ? "visibility" : "visibility_off"
                }}
              </mat-icon>
              <mat-error> Password Doesn't match!</mat-error>
            </mat-form-field>
          </div>

          <div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutGap="1rem">
            <button class="button-section" mat-raised-button>
              <span class="btn-text">Change</span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
```

TS:

```
export class ChangePasswordComponent implements OnInit {
  changePasswordForm!: FormGroup;
  newPasswordVisibility = false;
  presentPasswordVisibility = false;
  confirmNewPasswordVisibility = false;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.initForm();
  }

  initForm = () => {
    this.changePasswordForm = new FormGroup({
      presentPassword: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
      newPassword: new FormControl(null, [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.pattern(/^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z\d]{8,16}$/),
      ]),
      confirmNewPassword: new FormControl(null, [
        Validators.required,
        this.matchPasswordValidator,
      ]),
    });
  };

  hasError = (control: string, error: string) => {
    this.changePasswordForm.controls[control].hasError(error);
  };

  matchPasswordValidator = (control: AbstractControl) => {
    if (control && control.value) {
      const passwordControl = control.root.get('confirmNewPassword');
      if (control.value !== passwordControl?.value) {
        return { hasError: true };
      }
    }
    return null;
  };

  submit = () => {
    console.log(this.changePasswordForm.value);
    if (this.changePasswordForm.valid) {
      console.log('valid');
    } else {
      console.log('Not valid');
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: your `hasError` function is missing `return`...

Comment: can you please pass '' blank string in initForm function?

Comment: @AmanGojariya you meant it?

initForm = () => {
    console.log(null);
    this.changePasswordForm = new FormGroup({
      presentPassword: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
      newPassword: new FormControl(null, [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.pattern(/^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z\d]{8,16}$/),
      ]),
      confirmNewPassword: new FormControl(null, [
        Validators.required,
        this.matchPasswordValidator,
      ]),
    });
  };

Comment: It means, initForm = () => { this.changePasswordForm = new FormGroup({ presentPassword: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]), newPassword: new FormControl('', [ Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z\d]{8,16}$/), ]), confirmNewPassword: new FormControl('', [ Validators.required, this.matchPasswordValidator, ]), }); };

Comment: @SurajRao Yes it resolved that error showing issue. But still form is taking null values. but showing error as "password is required"

Comment: Please replace with my code

Comment: either 'presentPassword' or 'newPassword' is failing.. You could change the wording for one to know which is failing. Also, unrelated issue: `matchPasswordValidator` should probably have `control.root.get('newPassword')`

Comment: @AmanGojariya yes I did so. I also consoled the values of form. and it is showing like this.

{presentPassword: "", newPassword: "", confirmNewPassword: ""}

But actually It shouldn't haved showed value as I have set validators as required. Then how can it pass null value?

Comment: can you please create stackblitz?

Comment: any errors in console?

Comment: @AmanGojariya May be you can access details from this. "https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-2dnawg"

Comment: @SurajRao No there's no error is console. I have built a slackbuiltz of this. You can check from here. "https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-2dnawg"

Comment: The stackblitz link seems to be working... type the passwords with correct format and click change

Comment: @SurajRao Yes. But if I doesn't put any value, It is showing null value. But in form control I set validators as required.

Also  "this.changePasswordForm.valid" isn't true. So, it's entering into else scope. I am not sure why this form is not valid!

Comment: if you use ReactiveForms use the validators when create the form, **not** use in .html `pattern="^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z\d]{8,16}$"`

Comment: if no value is put, the form does not meet your validator requirements i.e. `Validator.required` so at first it will be invalid. Not sure what you expect here

Comment: @SurajRao Yes. But even if I was sending values through forms, it was showing Invalid. 

But main problem was in matchPasswordValidator() function. And fixed it!